# jQuery timeout function after validation

Tags: jquery, timeout, validation

I use this function to validate my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tracks_form').validate({ 
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            form.submit(); 
        }
    })
 });
</script>
```

What I need is to create a timeout function inside this one.

so, as soon as the form has been validated, it will stop the page for about 2-3 seconds and THEN will finally submit the form.

How do I modify this function to achieve this result?

Thank you so much!

Comment: you can use `.delay` http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay the form submit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tracks_form').validate({ 
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           setTimeout(function(){
             form.submit(); 
           }, 3000);//Time in milliseconds
        }
    })
 });
```